# Finding the lowest number over 10 in a nested/flat list of strings and integers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to extract the lowest number over 10 from a list of nested and unnested strings and integers for each item. I've tried a few different things but they either return nothing or a few different error messages (expected string or buffer, '>' not possible between int and list were two of them). They need to remain in order because they will be entered into a pandas data frame afterwards.

```
starting_list = [['4dfg', '12kfmgfg','dfgdf133'],[8, '16dgdfg'], 11, '', 'fdsf']

desired_result = [12, 16, 11, NaN, NaN]
```

Below are 2 of the different functions I've tried. Because the results are going into a data frame, a pandas-based answer would also be fine.

```
def min_int(data):
    for item in range(len(data)):
        for i in range(len(data[item])):
            if type(data[item][i]) == int:
                if data[item][i] >10:
                    data.remove(data[item][i])
            else:
                data[item][i] =int(re.sub(r'\D', "", data[item]))
                if data[item][i] >10:
                    data.remove(data[item][i])
        data[item] = min(data)

def remove_text(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        try:
            for ii in range(len(data[i])):
                try:
                    data[i][ii] =int(re.sub(r'\D', "", data[item]))
                except:
                    continue
        except:
            continue
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain, in plain English words, the logic that gets you from the specified input to the desired output. Include each step of the process that you would follow, when doing the computation by hand. It seems, for example, like there are at least three cases when you consider one of the elements of `starting_list`: it could be an integer, a string, or a list. None of the code you show seems to be attempting to consider all three possibilities at once.

Comment: You should try to write a function that gives you the correct result for a single element of `starting_list`, and then use it to get the overall result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
s = pd.Series(data)
a = (pd.to_numeric(s.explode() #explode lists
                     .astype(str) #convert all values to strings
                     .str.replace(r'\D', ''), errors='coerce') #replace and convert to numbers if possible
                     .loc[lambda x: x > 10] #filter values
                     .min(level=0) #get minimal per index
                     .reindex(s.index) #add removed values of index
                     .tolist()) #convert to list

#convert non NaNs to integers
a = [int(x) if x == x else x for x in a]
print (a)
[12, 16, 11, nan, nan]
```

Your function should be simplify:

```
def try_to_int(x):
    try:
        return int(re.sub(r'\D', "", x))
    except:
        return np.nan

def min_int(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        gen = (try_to_int(y) for y in x)
        return min(y for y in gen if y == y and y > 10)
    else:
        return try_to_int(x)
        

print ([min_int(x) for x in starting_list])
[12, 16, 11, nan, nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you already have an accepted answer by pandas-wiz @jezrael, here is a lower-level approach, if you like.

Essentially, it uses regex to extract the numeric values, and filters to meet your requirement, then appends them to an output list.

```
import re

exp = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

new = []
for i in list_:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        new2 = []
        for j in i:
            f = exp.findall(str(j))
            new2.append(int(f[0]) if f else float('nan'))
        new.append(min(i for i in new2 if i > 10))
    else:
        f = exp.findall(str(i))
        new.append(int(f[0]) if f else float('nan'))
```

Output:

```
>>> [12, 16, 11, nan, nan]
```

Setup:

```
list_ = [['4dfg', '12kfmgfg', 'dfgdf133'],
         [8, '16dgdfg'],
         11,
         '',
         'fdsf']
```

Answer (score -1):

You may create a generator:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
import re


def select_numbers(items, limit=10):
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str):
            yield from select_numbers(item, limit)
        else:
            item = re.sub(r"\D", "", str(item))
            if item == "":
                yield float("NaN")
            elif int(item) > limit:
                yield int(item)
```

---

*Testing it:*

```
>>> starting_list = [['4dfg', '12kfmgfg','dfgdf133'],[8, '16dgdfg'], 11, '', 'fdsf']
>>>
>>> desired_result = select_numbers(starting_list)       # generator, not a list
>>> list(desired_result)
```

> ```
> [12, 133, 16, 11, nan, nan]
> ```

```
>>> desired_result = select_numbers(starting_list)      # re-creating exhausted generator
>>>
>>> for elem in desired_result:                         # direct use of generator in loop
>>>     print(elem)
```

> ```
> 12
> 133
> 16
> 11
> nan
> nan
> ```

Comment: Per OP’s requirements, 133 should not be listed in the output.

Comment: @S3DEV, I don't see such a requirement, either in the OP question, or in their comment.

Comment: “I'm trying to extract the lowest number over 10 ...” and 
`desired_result = [12, 16, 11, NaN, NaN]`

Comment: @S3DEV, you're probably right. Not very clear specification for me, and not only for me — see the first comment under the question.